# Batch CSV unwanted Character in MAC on an Computer with XP, but not on Win 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv, character, mac-address

A batch file, containing the below code is run on computers

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set file="%~dp0%computername%.csv"
echo Domain,DIR,Site,Team,Location,Post,Name,NHIS_NO,PC_Serial,Service_Asset_Tag,OS,Sys_Type,Model,Sys_MACs,Phone_MAC,OS_SP,Local_Printers,Network_Printers_Paths,Network_Printers_Types,Account_Names,Shared_Drive_letters,Shared_Drive_Paths,Notes>>%file%
echo ... (rest of code)
echo %userdomain%,,,,,,,,%PC_Serial%,%Service_Tag%,%osname%,,%model%,!Sys_MACs!,,%sp%,%Local_Printers%,!printers_network_names!,!printers_network_types!,!Account_Names!,!drive_letters_Wmic_final4!,!drive_paths_Wmic_final2!,!Notes!>> %file%
```

On the computer with Win 7 (ver 6.1.7601) the output in the .csv (when viewed in notepad.exe) is not split (onto a new line) after the value for `%Sys_MACs%` which is `90-B1-1C-5E-44-86`.

However on a computer with XP (ver 5.1.2600) the output *is* split (onto a new line) after the value for `%Sys_MACs%`, which is the issue.

Looking at the differences I noticed that the MAC address in the XP output in Notepad is: `00-1E-4F-C6-03-C9□`. Ie a small square after the MAC address.

The code which saves the MAC addresses into %Sys_MACs% was below i):

```
if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt
ipconfig /all|find "Physical Address">macaddress.txt
for /f "tokens=2* delims=:" %%i in (macaddress.txt) do Set Sys_MACs=!Sys_MACs!^|%%i
echo Sys_MACs are: !Sys_MACs!
if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt
```

Then using suggestion in 1st comment ii):

```
if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt
ipconfig /all|find "Physical Address">macaddress.txt
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims=:" %%i in ('type macaddress.txt') do Set Sys_MACs=!Sys_MACs!^|%%i
echo Sys_MACs are: !Sys_MACs!
if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt
```

Then using suggestion in 2nd comment it is iii):

```
if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt
if exist macaddress_ascii.txt del macaddress_ascii.txt
ipconfig /all|find "Physical Address">macaddress.txt
type macaddress.txt>macaddress_ascii.txt
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims=:" %%i in ('type macaddress_ascii.txt') do Set Sys_MACs=!Sys_MACs!^|%%i
echo Sys_MACs are: !Sys_MACs!
if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt
```

Using suggestions in 3rd comment it is

iv):
        if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt
    if exist macaddress_ascii.txt del macaddress_ascii.txt
    ipconfig /all|find "Physical Address">macaddress.txt
    type macaddress.txt>macaddress_ascii.txt
    for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims=:" %%i in ('CMD /U /C TYPE macaddress_ascii.txt') do Set Sys_MACs=!Sys_MACs!^|%%i
    echo Sys_MACs are: !Sys_MACs!
    if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt

and v):
    if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt
    if exist macaddress_ascii.txt del macaddress_ascii.txt
    ipconfig /all|find "Physical Address">macaddress.txt
    type macaddress.txt>macaddress_ascii.txt
    for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims=:" %%i in ('CMD /A /C TYPE macaddress_ascii.txt') do Set Sys_MACs=!Sys_MACs!^|%%i
    echo Sys_MACs are: !Sys_MACs!
    if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt

When `%Sys_MACs%` is echoed on the XP computer in cmd for i), ii) and iii) it is shown as: `00-1E-4F-C6-03-C9` ie no square shown for all. iv) does not output the MAC address, and v) echoes the MAC without the square.

Content of macaddress.txt:

```
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1E-4F-C6-03-C9
```

Content of macaddress_ascii.txt:

```
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1E-4F-C6-03-C9
```

Q: What would cause the square to show in the .csv when viewed in Notepad?

Ans: Probably unicode characters in the `macaddress.txt` file.

Q: What can be done to stop the square or any other unwanted characters to appear in the .csv (which means that 1 line is instead split into (potentially) multiple?

Stopping / removing unicode characters going into `%Sys_MACs%`. No solution that works as of yet. I beginning to think that the line `for /f` loop may need to be tweaked further. 
Will do further research.

Any further comments / answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code I altered from the GetMACXP.bat source code on http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=getmacxp_nt

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('ipconfig /all 2^>NUL ^| FINDSTR /R /I /C:"[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-*[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-*[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-*[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-*[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-*[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]"') DO Set !Sys_MACs!^|%%A
```

I then stripped out "Physical Address ", dots, colons, and spaces from `%Sys_MACs%`

Resulting in no square after the MAC address in on the XP machine in the .csv file `%file%`.

@JasonFaulkner - thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be unicode characters have slipped into the output which is causing them to flow through to your CSV generation. You can use the `TYPE` command to strip these out.

Try this:

```
if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt
ipconfig /all|find "Physical Address">macaddress.txt

REM Convert output to ASCII.
TYPE macaddress.txt>macaddress_ascii.txt

REM Process ASCII output.
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims=:" %%i in (`TYPE macaddress_ascii.txt`) do Set Sys_MACs=!Sys_MACs!^|%%i

echo Sys_MACs are: !Sys_MACs!
if exist macaddress.txt del macaddress.txt
if exist macaddress_ascii.txt del macaddress_ascii.txt
```

Comment: After making the code change to `for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims=:" %%i in ('TYPE macaddress.txt')`, and testing this on the XP computer, the square after the MAC is still present. I'll update the question reflecting this in a moment.

Comment: @NickProwse - Try redirecting the output of `TYPE` to a file and then processing that file. I've updated the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: I've made the code change in your edited answer and still get the square after the MAC address. I'll update the question with the contents of macaddress.txt and macaddress_ascii.txt. I'm thinking that it may be something that needs to be changed in the line of the `for` loop?

Comment: @NickProwse - You can try changing the for loop command (what is between the backticks) to a command shell instance which runs in unicode: `CMD /U /C TYPE macaddress_ascii.txt` Alternately, instead of `/U` you could try `/A` for ANSI support instead of unicode... worth a shot both ways.

Comment: `CMD /U /C TYPE macaddress_ascii.txt` doesn't produce a MAC address when put in loop, and `CMD /A /C TYPE macaddress_ascii.txt` produces one but latter still has the square in the output.